# How to delete old versions of tables in Delta Lake

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake

As I understand from documentation, delta lake allows to roll back or "time travel", as they say, to some specific version of a table. But how can I make sure that deleting data will actually delete it without creating a new version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be implemented using vaccum of the Delta Lake and if the retention is set.
Please refer :
https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-utility.html#delta-vacuum